# My search button gets disable when i move down using tab or keys from input text field to select dropdown

Tags: jquery

I have 4 fields out of which first two are input fields and the last two are select dropdown.The issue i am facing here is when i try to move down from input field to select dropdown using tab key or normally,my search button gets disabled because of the disable attribute which is getting added.I tried implementing like this but its not working.The code is working fine for input field with keyup function.I do not have any common class for select and input else i could have used `$('.class').on('keyup change', function ())`.How to achieve that.`".select_group"` is the class for last two select dropdowns.

```
if(jQuery.trim($emailAdd.val()) != "" || jQuery.trim($fIdAdd.val()) != "" || jQuery.trim($mNQAdd.val()) != "") 
        $('#btn_search').attr('disabled',false);        
    else 
        $('#btn_search').attr('disabled',true);
        $('input[type="text"],.select_group').on('keyup change click', function () {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
           $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
     });
```

I have added the lines to make it work as initially it was not even working for input text fields.

```
$('input[type="text"],.select_group').on('keyup change click', function () {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
           $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
     });
```

Let me know how to make it work for input text fields and select dropdowns as well when i move down using any key or tab.Please help.

Comment: Can you perhaps create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to showcase the problem? I don't really understand how the button can get disabled just like that.

Comment: post your total code

Comment: I am already using fiddle.And that is an existing issue which i am trying to resolve.

Comment: No, you are not using fiddle. For your personal use isn't useful for us. Share the fiddle link to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 $('input[type="submit"]').prop("disabled", false);
```

This propagates in the DOM the property. 
If this is not the problem, please, make a jsFiddle to reproduce it.

### EDIT

What's the content of `$(this).val()` ?? Do you know it?

### EDIT 2

If this is your code:

```
if(jQuery.trim($emailAdd.val()) != "" || jQuery.trim($fIdAdd.val()) != "" || jQuery.trim($mNQAdd.val()) != "") 
    $('#btn_search').attr('disabled',false);        
else 
    $('#btn_search').attr('disabled',true);
    $('input[type="text"],.select_group').on('keyup change click', function () {
    if($(this).val() != '') {
       $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
 });
```

You must to learn how if-else statements needs the brackets `{}` to limit the functionality. This works:

```
if(jQuery.trim($emailAdd.val()) != "" || jQuery.trim($fIdAdd.val()) != "" || jQuery.trim($mNQAdd.val()) != "") {
    $('#btn_search').attr('disabled',false);        
} else {
    $('#btn_search').attr('disabled',true);
    $('input[type="text"], .select_group').on('keyup change click', function () {
        if($(this).val() != '') {
            $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
     });
 }
```

Comment: removeAttr is working fine.The only thing is keyup will not work for select dropdowns.Probably we need to use .change function.But i am wondering how to accomodate in my code.

Comment: if(jQuery.trim($emailAdd.val()) != "" || jQuery.trim($fIdAdd.val()) != "" || jQuery.trim($mNQAdd.val()) != "") $('#btn_search').attr('disabled',false);
else $('#btn_search').attr('disabled',true); $('input[type="text"],.select_group').on('keyup change click', function () { if($(this).val() != '') { $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled'); } });

Comment: $(this).val() is the input fields value .

Comment: Yes, I know that `$(this).val()` is the value, but what is the value? You have an if condition, maybe you don't enter in if statement.

Comment: Please, see the **EDIT 2** zone in my answer.

Comment: Thanks Marcos,but i have tried with .on to bind keyup and change event for input and select before.Tried again.Still not working.

Comment: Are you trying like I say to you for the `{} ` in if-else statement?

Comment: Please, don't waste my time and make a jsfiddle.com. We tell you several times